# ReactJS State returning default value in some functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I have a ReactJS file where at the top I have one of my states defined as

`const [items, setItems] = useState(0);`

This updates a value I show on the screen properly, and when I read the value of `items` in some functions, I do get the proper value of `items`. However, on one specific function with the prototype of `const updateCart = (client) => {}`, when I try to get the value of `items`, I get the default value defined in the `useState(0);`. I do understand that states do not always update instantly, but even after reading the value correctly in another function, when I try to read it in the `updateCart()` function I always get the default value, not the current value. How can I read the current value in my `updateCart()` function?

Thank you

EDIT: Added relevant code

```
const Checkout = () => {
     const [items, setItems] = useState(0);

     var requestBusy = false;
     const requestClient = () => {
        if (!requestBusy) {
          requestBusy = true;

          console.log("Sending request");
          ipcRenderer.send('request-client', 'request_client_checkout');
    
          ipcRenderer.on('response_client_checkout', (event, arg) => {
            requestBusy = false;
            Server.getClientFromUID(arg, (success, client) => {
                if (success) {
                    console.log(client);
                    updateCart(client);
                } else {
                    setErrorMessage("Unknown client");
                }
            });
          });
        }
      }

     const updateCart = (client) => {
          console.log(`Items: ${items}`); // This shows the default value of items
          //...
     }

     const updateQty = e => {
          var newItems = 0;
        if (e.currentTarget.getAttribute('value') === "del") {
            newItems = (items / 10 | 0); // THIS READS CORRECT VALUE OF items
        } else if (e.currentTarget.getAttribute('value') === "clr") {
            //
        } else {
            newItems = ((items * 10) + parseInt(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('value'))); // THIS READS CORRECT VALUE OF items
        }

        setItems(newItems);
     }

     useEffect(() => {
        ipcRenderer.send('DiscoverReader', "");
        requestClient();
     }, []);

     return(
          <div>
               <h1>Items: {items}</h1> // THIS SHOWS CORRECT VALUE
               <div className="keypad">
                    <button className="keypad_7" value="7" onClick={ updateQty }>
                         <span>7</span>
                    </button>
                    <button className="keypad_8" value="8" onClick={ updateQty }>
                         <span>8</span>
                    </button>
                    <button className="keypad_9" value="9" onClick={ updateQty }>
                         <span>9</span>
                    </button>
                    <button className="keypad_4" value="4" onClick={ updateQty }>
                         <span>4</span>
                    </button>
                    <button className="keypad_5" value="5" onClick={ updateQty }>
                         <span>5</span>
                    </button>
                    <button className="keypad_6" value="6" onClick={ updateQty }>
                         <span>6</span>
                    </button>
                    <button className="keypad_1" value="1" onClick={ updateQty }>
                         <span>1</span>
                    </button>
                    <button className="keypad_2" value="2" onClick={ updateQty }>
                         <span>2</span>
                    </button>
                    <button className="keypad_3" value="3" onClick={ updateQty }>
                         <span>3</span>
                    </button>
                    <button className="keypad_clr" value="clr" onClick={ updateQty }>
                         <span>Clear</span>
                    </button>
                    <button className="keypad_0" value="0" onClick={ updateQty }>
                         <span>0</span>
                    </button>
                    <button className="keypad_del" value="del" onClick={ updateQty }>
                         <span className="fas fa-backspace"></span>
                    </button>
               </div>
          </div>
     );
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code; it sounds like you may have incorrectly memoized the function so it gets stuck at the first value, i.e. using `useCallback` with an empty dependency array. But without code we can't tell.

Comment: @Jayce444 Hello. I added the relevant code and an example of where the value is shown properly and another where it is not. Thank you for your response

Comment: Your code doesn't show a use of `updateCart`.

Comment: @AndyRay Sorry, I forgot to add the call fo updateCart in my question. It is added now

Comment: Hi, @Jayce444, FrankFabregat2. I also facing same issue. Is there any solution for this?